# return a table with a column with yes or no

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

Singers

```
identification    name
-------------------------
      20          Bolton
      21          Madonna
      22          Nirvana
      23          Hendrix
```

Colaborate

```
first_singer_id     second_singer_id       genre
---------------------------------------------------
      20                  21               pop
      21                  23               pop
      22                  21               rock
      23                  20               rock
      23                  21               metal
      23                  21               hiphop
      23                  22               pop
```

I want to get a result where every name of the singers table has stated in a second column whether or not they sing metal. So for example Hendrix and Madonna sing metal so the table should look like this:

```
name     metal
--------------
Bolton   N
Madonna  Y
Nirvana  N
Hendrix  Y
```

I have tried the following but I don't get distinct results nor does it take into account the symmetric relation of Colaborate.

```
select case when C.genre= 'metal' then "Y" else "N" end as genre, S1.name 
from   Colaborate C
       JOIN Singers S1
       ON S1.identification = C.first_singer_id
       JOIN Singers S2
       ON S2.identification = C.second_singer_id
```

How can I solve this with a CASE expression?

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: This would be easier in a relational database with normalized data - if you restructure your `collaborate` table to be `songs` with columns `song_id` and `genre`, and then add another table (`song_singers`) with columns `song_id` and  `singer_id`. Then you can do this with `JOIN`s only, no need for additional `GROUP BY` or other subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ascertain this a number of ways, one way would be using `exists`

```
Select name,
  case when exists (select * from colaborate c where c.first_singer_id=s.identification and genre='metal')
         or exists (select * from colaborate c where c.second_singer_id=s.identification and genre='metal')
  then 'Y' else 'N' end as Metal
from Singers s
```

Comment: With the right indexes, this is probably the fastest method.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables with a `LEFT` join and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.genre = 'metal' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) metal
FROM Singers s LEFT JOIN Colaborate c
ON s.identification IN (c.first_singer_id, c.second_singer_id)
GROUP BY s.identification, s.name
```

Comment: Because it's the primary key, it's sufficient to group by s.identification.

Comment: @Schwern yes it is the primary key, but the name should also be returned and this is why it must be included in the group by clause.

Comment: Can you explain the `MAX` logic in your `SELECT`? Does this work strictly because "Y" > "N"?

Comment: @forpas I understand. Because s.identification is the primary key, it's unique, it's not necessary to have s.name in the group by to use it in the select.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones exactly.

Comment: @Schwern if name is not included in the group by clause the code would not even run in most databases.

Comment: @forpas Because s.identification is the primary key, s.name has a functional dependency on it. `group by s.identification` and `group by s.identification, s.name` are the same. This is standard SQL and works in SQLite, Postgres, and MySQL. SQL Server and Oracle remain in their own worlds.

Comment: @Schwern It may be a SQL standard but it is not implemented as such (like in MySql where you have to disable only_full_group_by setting) or not at all. So in a question tagged only SQL I would propose only working code in any case.

Comment: @forpas [Works in MySQL with `only_full_group_by` on](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8074b56274b6196b1fccdb2a672d580c).

Comment: @Schwern no it does not work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0aaed4b6c98103291646348ce4bf81c7

Comment: @forpas [It does when you declare your primary key](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2236f097f895ef8af2914c5c5c471f58).

Comment: @forpas It's fine to go the conservative route and keep it in, but the "every column in select must also be in group by" rule of thumb is just a rule of thumb.

Comment: @Schwern right, still would you post code in a question tagged sql that (maybe) would not work? I would not.

Answer (score 0):

first_singer_id, second_singer_id, ... indicates the schema could be done better. What happens if *three* singers collaborate? Or [thirty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AjkUyX0rVw)?

Lists in SQL are done with join tables. If you restructure your data like so...

```
create table songs (
  id bigint primary key generate always as identity,
  name text not null,
  genre text not null
);

create table singers (
  id bigint primary key generate always as identity,
  name text not null
);

create table song_singers (
  song_id bigint not null references songs(id),
  singer_id bigint not null references singers(id)
);
```

Now you can have as many singers per song as you like. You still need to aggregate the resulting rows, and [forpas's technique works well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67097883/14660), but without the self-joins.

```
select
  singers.name,
  max(case songs.genre when 'metal' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as genre
from singers
left join song_singers on singers.id = song_singers.singer_id
left join songs on songs.id = song_singers.song_id
group by singers.id
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63fecb553ff1f660f65ba99e3aaa9241).